# Regular expressions and multiple writing systems

Tags: regex

Types of writing systems:

- Alphabet
- Abjad
- Abugida
- Syllabary
- Logography

In regular expressions we need to tell which "chars" we want to validate:

We use something like this a-zA-Z0-9 to say that we accept all the alphanumeric.

How can we make regular expressions that validate other writing systems non-alphanumerics?
(how can I make a regular expression that will validate chinese, or indian, or greek or russian, or someother?

UPDATE:

Using ASP.NET regex engine.

If you don't mind, could you provide me some examples?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What regex engine are you using? If you are using [Java](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) or [.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972966.aspx), there are many different unicode categories you can use, such as `\p{InGreek}`.

Another solution, which is perhaps more generic, is to use **unicode ranges**. This [page](http://kourge.net/projects/regexp-unicode-block) contains a list of several well known unicode ranges. For instance, if you want to match a Tibetan character, you would use `[\u0F00-\u0FFF]`. If you want to match a Tibetan character and English characters, you could use `[A-Za-z\u0F00-\u0FFF]`, *et cetera*.

If you want to match several languages, you can use the page that I mentioned to lookup the languages' unicode range, and combine them. For example, the unicode range `[\u0370-\u06FF]` covers Greek, Cyrillic (used in Russian languages and other Slavic languages), Hebrew and Arabic. If you need more, just add the ranges you need until all languages are covered.

---

**EDIT**: Based on your comments, you can just use the following expression:

```
@"\p{L}{4,10}"
```

**`\p{L}`** or **`\p{Letter}`** is used to match a letter from any language so, the above expression matches 4 to 10 letters from any language.

Comment: Is it possible to have only one regex to match all the languages? At least to see if they write something between 4 to 10 chars? (this is the basic expression).

Answer (score 0):

+1 to @JG
Also you can use predefined charset classes. If  ECMAScript option not specified then \w treated as any word character - for unicode is "what doctor ordered". The same \d is decimal digits and so on..